# Latent feature extraction using dnn and word2vec embeddings

Tags: nlp, word2vec

I recently read a journal about a tag-aware recommender system. There is a part in the paper which I do not understand.

They used word2vec first and using embeddings as input to a DNN to extract latent features. I'm not sure what could the latent features be. Could anyone give me some hints?

[image]

[image]